# How to "Rostopic echo" only the pose in the 'odom' topic

Tags: gazebo, navigation, odometry, turtlebot, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner in ROS, and as such I'm struggling with an apparently simple question. I'm using Turtlbot in Gazebo and would like to print in a text file the pose of the robot during its path. What I do now is to "echo" the /odom topic and there I can see the pose. However, it prints a lot of other information I do not need. How can I somehow filter it, to only print the pose of the robot (x, y, z) during the robot's path.

Thank you in advance for considering this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54895/how-to-%22rostopic-echo%22-only-the-pose-in-the-%27odom%27-topic/) by [Evis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4178/evis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-02-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use slash `/` for name resolution, i.e. to go deeper into the objects and structures.

In your case it should be something like:

```
$ rostopic echo /odom/pose/pose/position
```

It should return `x`, `y` and `z` all of type `float64`.

That is because [Odometry](http://ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) message has field `pose` which is of type `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance`, which has another `pose` of type `geometry_msgs/Pose` and then there are two fields -- `position` and `orientation`.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-02-11**:
My typing took too long, didn't see the previous answer.

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2015-11-10**:
Thanks, but what about when there is an array structure in the middle, how to go deeper ? I posted my question here : http://answers.ros.org/question/220434/rostopic-echo-of-a-field-of-an-array-in-ros-indigo/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just try `rostopic echo /odom/pose`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous60874](https://answers.ros.org/users/60874/anonymous60874/) on 2021-07-13**:
I'm grateful